# What do those little squiggly symbol on events in Apple iCal mean?

Tags: macos, calendar.app

The symbol, which looks exactly like a sine wave in a tiny circle, seems to be appearing in the upper right hand corner of all recent entries in my iCal program. I can find no reference to that symbol anywhere in Apple's documentation.

It was only in one repeating entry that I put in many months ago, but now it appears in all new entries.  It even appears in copies of entries that don't have the symbol.

What does this little squiggly symbol on events mean?

Answer (score 3):

It means that the calendar in question is not syncing.